# Classification of reflection operators

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reflection

How do you call a reflection operator whose matrix $R\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal of $\pm1$, i.e. the operator flips the signs of some coordinates?

For example in dimension 3: $R = I;\quad R = \text{diag}(1,-1,1); \quad R = -I$.

I found that $R = -I$ is called a [point reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection), but I couldn't find a complete classification for other types of reflections.

Thanks!
p.

Comment: Presumably you call them just what you called them. They are not all reflections, but rather some would be called improper rotations. Since yours act on the coordinate axes, you might choose to call them coordinate improper rotations or coordinate reflections. I would call them diagonal orthogonal matrices.

Comment: why are they not all reflections?  is a point reflection not a reflection?

Comment: A point reflection is not a reflection, since "reflection" by itself is short for reflection across a hyperplane. A reflection across a hyperplane fixes every point in the plane, but point reflections invert every point across the origin. In $2n$ dimensions, a point reflection is a composition of $180^{\circ}$ rotations in $n$ perpendicular planes, and same for $2n+1$ dimensions but also a reflection across the hyperplane spanned by the $n$ planes.